# How to detect if a request comes from a progressive-web-app on the backend

Tags: node.js, progressive-web-apps

I am coding currently a progressive-web-app. I would like to be able to determine in the request whether or no the client is making the request from a PWA or not. Apparently the code below can be used for clientside detection but I'd like to know on the backend for some functionality I'm planning. Thanks

```
isInWebAppiOS = (window.navigator.standalone == true);
isInWebAppChrome = (window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches);
```

Comment: Use the client side detection and then add a custom header or a query parameter when you send requests from the PWA client. This way the server will get the information the client sends. This of course can be intentionally altered.

Comment: I agree I could do that, I'm hoping to avoid it though and wondering if there is something I can do serverside only. @WiktorZychla

Comment: The usual way is to add query string to the url requested from PWA.

Comment: @Anthony: unless you do something explicit, the server has no way to distinguish requested.

Comment: Okay thanks @WiktorZychla, I suppose the user-agent will come back the same as a browser then. Wasn't sure but I figured I should ask the question since I couldn't find it yet on Stackoverflow. If you want to submit that as an answer I'll accept it, thank you